# Magento - Display Out of Stock Products time execution

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a large mysql database, so when i'm trying to set Display Out of Stock Products options in NO, i get php time execution error. Does anybody know native mysql query or some another trick to change this options? Please help. It's a shared hosting so i can't increase execution time of script

Answer (score 1):

You could paginate your list and use MySQL `LIMIT <start>,<length>` options.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (1=1) LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The above will select the first 100 items. For the next page, increase the first value by 100, and so on until there are no more rows.

Comment: tnx. i don't know structure of magento tables, so i don't know exactly what query i need

Comment: if you have access to querying the database, I assume you have the possibility to figure out the database structure?

Comment: yes,but database is so complicated and have many tables, maybe somebody already do something similar